# How to undo deletion of code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, undo

So I was working on a small project and accidentally deleted a large chunk of code. Is there any `undo` button or something so that I can undo this change?

Comment: a good lesson to use version control or some sort of backup, it was a `small` project so when you rewrite you can make it better

Answer (score 1):

Try entering `CTRL + Z`
it might work if you haven't closed vscode

Comment: nope sadly CTRL Z doesn't work even while not closing vs code :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is effective for code editing. However, if you modify times or close vsocde , it cannot be completely restored.